# How to determine why connection creation lasts so long?

Tags: postgresql, java

On one of my servers (Windows 2008 Server), creating connection in Java to PostgreSQL server takes from 1,5 to 4 seconds! I have no clue how to start checking what can be wrong. I tried different database on this server, different user. Still the same. If I work with backup of database on my computer, it's 150ms. I would be grateful for any tip where to start.

Comment: How long it is when you try to connect to PostgreSQL by `psql` or `telnet`?

Comment: I answer myself - it was SSL set to on.

Comment: SSL is on by default on major linux distros like ubuntu and debian. It does not generally add several seconds to the connection time. As an example, I connect to PG/SSL in 0.08s locally and 0.2s remotely through a WAN.

Comment: It's Windows 2008, not linux. You can believe or not, turning off SSL resulted in shortening acquiring connection time and general SQL queries time :) Weird, but I am happy I am through it already.

Comment: I've seen similar problem when you don't have a working DNS config. This is often a problem if the server tries to resolve the hostname of better logging or authentication.

Comment: @Michal - If you found an answer to your question, please add it as a full an answer. Makes it easier for people to find the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself - it was SSL set to on.  Setting `ssl` to `off` in `postgresql.conf` solved the problem.

Comment: Turning off SSL -  but how?  Where?  Only for that connection in Java or globally on the Windows server?  Or in PostgreSQL?

Comment: in PostgreSQL .conf file. It's disabled by default.

Comment: Several seconds delay is not explainable by SSL alone (unless the system is really really badly loaded). Is this a linux DB server? I suspect most likely due to a slow /dev/random on this machine. This is very typical for login slowdown (alas normally on the client). SSL does need extra random numbers.